# vuejs appending a binded url

Tags: templates, vue.js, vuejs2

In my vue template I have

```
<img class="workimg" v-bind:src="item.imagemobile">
```

I want to try and append it to

```
<img class="workimg" v-bind:src="/featured/item.imagemobile">
```

The syntax breaks the app, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `v-bind`, the value must be a JavaScript expression.

```
<img class="workimg" v-bind:src="`/featured/${item.imagemobile}`">
```

or

```
<img class="workimg" v-bind:src="'/featured/' + item.imagemobile">
```

should work.